# Accessing User.get_absolute_url in Django 1.7

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-1.7

I just upgraded from Django 1.5 to 1.7 and now my user objects don't have the `get_absolute_url` method on them.

This used to work:

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [2]: u = User.objects.get(pk=1)

In [3]: u.get_absolute_url()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5c5e8a279785> in <module>()
----> 1 u.get_absolute_url()

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'

In [4]:
```

For reference, this is what I have in my settings.py:

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda u: u'/course/profile/{0}'.format(u.username)
}
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Django 1.7, `AbstractUser` no longer defines a `get_absolute_url` method. This is mentioned in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#miscellaneous).

In Django 1.7, you could not use use `ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES` with models that do not have a `get_absolute_url` method. This was fixed in [ticket 11775](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11775#comment:6). You can use `ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES` with any model as of Django 1.7.1 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7.1/)).

Comment: I opened this pull request for the release notes: https://github.com/django/django/pull/3200 -- but as I mentioned, a backwards incompatible change should probably be added for this, right?

Guess I'm going to try using a custom user model solely for the purpose of getting this method back.

Comment: Django 1.7.1 has restored the ability to use `ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES` with the auth.user model. See the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7.1/)

Comment: For anyone with this issue again and using same syntax as Django docs:  ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda o: "/users/%s/" % o.username,
}